# SQL Server XML Parsing from Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

We have a table in a reporting system sql database that stores all the settings for each report in an XML string in a table column.

How can I use SQL to parse these XML strings for filtering and reporting on element values in each node?

In other words, I need to read XML out of a table column and parse it for existing nodes and values.

Update:  I have a table with over 500 records currently.  Each record is a report in an ad hoc reporting system.  The settings for each report is stored in an XML string in a data column.  An owner of that report is listed in a node inside that XML.  I need to both get the name of that node and produce a list of all owner values for each of the 500+ records using SQL.

Comment: Without specifics of your data the best anyone can offer is [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods).

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I was hoping to use a generic parsing method to help me learn about the data and XML structure.  The data is from a third party software that we do not control and need to understand their data.

Comment: Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL 
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to switch to XQuery.

Comment: You can parse any XML structure with SQL Server's XML methods, including (to some extent) dynamic structures. The only requirement is that you must know what sort of result set you're looking for, because T-SQL can't produce dynamic result sets (unless you dynamically construct the queries as well).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score -2):

SQL Server supports the XML datatype and querying elements in an XML field using OPENXML. This Transact-SQL documentation should be useful:

XML is supported in SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Definition of OPENXML:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Examples using OPENXML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/examples-using-openxml?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will review these links and see if they answer the question.

Comment: Don't use `OPENXML`. This is the pre-2005 way of supporting XML access in SQL Server; the XML methods (`.nodes()`, `.query()`) are conceptually much simpler and don't require the cumbersome management of handles (failure of which to do so properly can result in resource leaks).

Comment: Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL 
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to switch to XQuery.

Comment: Let me edit my question for further details.

Comment: SQL Server's XQuery API is a way to go.

Comment: Thank you!  XQuery API appears to be the way.  It's going to take me some time to review and implement.